# App Clip uncompressed size is larger than 10MB in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, cross-platform

i am developing application with app clip feature. app clip successfully integrated and working fine but not able to deploy it on app store for production due to 10 MB size limit.
I tried to exclude pods from app clip target but its removing pods from main app target as well. i am not able to exclude packages from appclip target.

Anyone have idea how to add `dependencies` in `pubsec.yaml` file platform & target wise? if we are not able to remove its pods from pods file.

```
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

# Define a variable to specify the excluded pods for AppClip target
excluded_pods_for_app_clip = [
  'Pod_Name',
  'Pod_Name',
]

target 'Runner' do
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

# Target for AppClip
target 'AppClip' do
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
      ]
    end
  end

  # Exclude specified pods for AppClip target
  if target.name == 'AppClip'
    excluded_pods_for_app_clip.each do |pod_name|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.native_target.dependencies.each do |dependency|
          if dependency.display_name == pod_name
            dependency.remove_from_project
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Following the [official site's](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/ios-app-clip) instructions to integrate an App Clip with Flutter, I've noticed that there's still an open [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71098). Other developers have also encountered this problem, and it seems that a solution has not been found yet.

Apple AppClip [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips)